# How do I change values,which are already used in a while loop?

Tags: processing

I am trying to write a program that displays spheres with a fixed spacing "d=19" in a rectangle. I only got it to work in the x and y axis direction or in the diagonal axis but not on the full area of the rectangle. I know the solution should be fairly easy but i cant seem to get it.

```
void setup() {
   size(600, 500);
   background(255);
}

void draw() {

    int x = 50;
    int y = 100;
    int r = 5;
    int d = 19;

    background(255);
    rect(x, y, mouseX-x, mouseY-y);

    while (y <= mouseY) {                 
        ellipse(x, y, 2*r, 2*r);

        while (x <= mouseX) {
          ellipse(x, y, 2*r, 2*r);
          x = x+d;
        }
        y = y+d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to reset the `x` coordinate before the inner loop of the nested loops. The circles have to be started in each row in the 1st column:

```java
void draw() {
    int x=50;
    int y=100;
    int r =5;
    int d =19;

    background(255);
    rect(x, y, mouseX-x, mouseY-y);

    while (y <= mouseY) {      

        x = 50; // <--- start at the begin in each row

        while (x <= mouseX) {
            ellipse(x, y, 2*r, 2*r);
            x=x+d;
        }
        y=y+d;
    }
}
```

Note, to draw the objects in a 2 dimensional grid, 2 nested loops are sufficient.